# Problem with npm and scrips. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: git, npm

This is project from udemy course everything was fine up untill point and in the course there is no explanation on what to do when this happens

```
npm run pub

> @szdravkovski86/common@1.0.4 pub C:\Users\Stefan\Desktop\ticketing\common
> git add . && git commit -m "Updates" && npm version patch && npm run build && npm publish

warning: in the working copy of 'package-lock.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'package.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @szdravkovski86/common@1.0.4 pub: `git add . && git commit -m "Updates" && npm version patch && npm run build && npm publish`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @szdravkovski86/common@1.0.4 pub script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-05T18_43_45_745Z-debug.log
```

i tried downgrading my npm version, npm cache clear --force  and i also tried deleting my node_modules  still didnt work. I just get another error when i delete node_modules